# Play 2.0 PostgreSQL Cannot connect to database [default] only on wireless

Tags: postgresql, networking

My Play 2.0 database is set up to use a PostgreSQL connection and it works fine on my wired internet connection. However, when I try to connect from a wireless internet connection i receive the Cannot connect to database [default] error. Can anyone please help me figure out why this is?

Settings:

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url=${DATABASE_URL}
db.default.partitionCount=1
```

Database URL variable set up in .bashrc file:

```
postgres://myusername:test123@localhost:5432/projectname
```

**EDITED:**

pg_hba.conf file:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     tvonehwegen                                md5
#host    replication     tvonehwegen        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     tvonehwegen        ::1/128                 md5
```

postgresql.conf file:

```
# - Connection Settings -

#listen_addresses = 'localhost'     # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                # comma-separated list of addresses;
                # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                # (change requires restart)
#port = 5432                # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
```

Turns out the only problem here is that I can not connect to my local postgreSQL database when I am connected to a wireless network. Does anyone know why that may be? Thanks!

Comment: "and it looks like my port in the table pg_settings is the same on a wired and wireless network (5432)." Wait, what? Why would it differ? Is the database also connected directly to the wireless network? If so, is it on the same machine, perhaps a laptop?

Comment: How are you connecting to it via the terminal? Are you sshing in to somewhere and then running `psql`?

Comment: The only reason I mentioned the port was because that was my only guess as to something that might change, but I was wrong. It is on the same machine both wired and wireless.

I am connecting to the database through terminal with the command:
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start

Comment: When you say wireless do you mean WiFi or 3G/4G? Check your IP address on wired and wireless. Is the server configured to block connections to certain ranges? This seems like a network/server configuration issue more than a Postgres/Scala/Play issue.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Your database is on `localhost`. Wired / WiFi / whatever should make absolutely no difference. My only guess is that you have a badly written firewall that gets turned on when you connect over WiFi, and it filters packets on the loopback interface (to/from localhost). Does it work when you aren't connected to either? Please *edit your question and explain how everything is connected together*.

Comment: Ok so I turned off my WIFI (duh, my database is local so I don't need internet to access it. Brain fart on my part), and I was able to connect to the database. For some reason, whenever I have my WIFI turned on and connected to a wireless network, I can't connect to my database locally. It must be a firewall setting I need to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your WiFi/Internet settings for IPv6. On some networks your machine gets an IPv6 address in addition to the traditional IPv4 one. In such cases, usually, `localhost` gets mapped to `::1` instead of `127.0.0.1`; which means things will go wrong if you have setup `pg_hba.conf` to grant access based on IPv4 addresses.

Assuming firewall is off, e.g. on Redhat based systems `service iptables stop`, and the following snippets exists in relevant files:

`pg_hba.conf`:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

`postgresql.conf`:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

You should be able to connect to the desired database as follows:

```
$ psql -h ::1 -U USERNAME -d DATABASE
Password for user USERNAME: 
psql (9.1.11)
SSL connection (cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.

DATABASE=>
```

And

```
$ psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U USERNAME -d DATABASE
Password for user USERNAME: 
psql (9.1.11)
SSL connection (cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.

DATABASE=>
```

Finally Play's JDBC connection settings should be of the following form:

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/DATABASE"
db.default.user=USERNAME
db.default.password=PASSWORD
```

*NOTE: I'd strongly suggest you **never** use `localhost` in a connection string. 99.99% of the time what you need is `127.0.0.1`.*

Comment: Thanks for the information! My WIFI TCP/IP setting is:
Configure IPv6: Automatically

My pg_hba.conf file looks like:
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust

My server starts just fine - I can connect to and query my PostgreSQL database, but my Play webapp can't seem to be able to connect.

Comment: Try changing `trust` to `md5` in `pg_hba.conf`. JDBC needs to exchange a username & password pair with the database.

Comment: Upon checking closer that didn't seem to fix my problem. I edited my question to include my pg_hba.conf file. I tried changing all trusts to md5 and that didn't work either. Do you have any other ideas? Thanks for your time!

Comment: When connected to WiFi, what is the output of both `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U UID -d DATABASE` and `psql -h localhost -U UID -d DATABASE`? For `UID` and `DATABASE` use be the ones in your Play app.

Comment: psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U UID -d DATABASE logged me into my database. Output:
    psql (9.3.2)
    Type "help" for help.

psql -h localhost -U UID -d DATABASE asked me for my password, but it would not accept any passwords. I tried my user password for my machine and also test123 which is what I have my DATABASE_URL set up to be (postgres://username:test123@localhost:5432/databasename)

Comment: I believe the scenario is as I had suspected at first. Updated the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't seem to help. I tried changing the file to only what you had in your sample, as well as replacing the all of the code to your sample. My application log keeps saying that the connection is refused. 
"Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections."

Comment: Check `postgresql.conf`. Look for all the lines with `listen_addresses =` and update your question with those lines. We'll figure it out.

Comment: Append `listen_addresses = '*'` and restart PostgreSQL; then try connecting using `psql` like the comment I'd left earlier.

Comment: Unfortunately this still did not fix my error. Also, I am unable to connect to my database even when my wireless is off when I change "trust" in to "md5" in this line:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust

Comment: I was able to connect to my database through the terminal after the changes you suggested using both commands, but the app is still failing. Should my DATABASE URL be: DATABASE_URL=postgres://username:password@127.0.0.1:5432/databasename? And I should be connecting to: http://127.0.0.1:9000/ right?

Comment: Why do you suggest to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?